# SQL Oracle - better way to to write update and delete query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have around 270 million rows indexed on month||id_nr and below update/delete query takes around 4 hours to complete.
I was wondering if there is any other way to do update/delete which will be faster.

Update Query:-

```
update table_A
set STATUS='Y'
where
month||id_nr in (select distinct month||id_nr from table_A where STATUS='Y');
```

Delete Query:-

```
Delete from table_B
where
month||id_nr in (select distinct month||id_nr from table_A where STATUS='Y');
```

Comment: The use of `SET STATUS='Y'` is not valid for a delete command.

Comment: That was a copy paste mistake, edited my question

Comment: Please post a query plans and index definition. It is a requirement for performance related questions according to the tag question guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why the string concatenation? And never try to force the DBMS to make rows distinct in an `IN` clause. Let the DBMS decide what it considers the best approach to look up the data.

So, just:

```
where (month, id_nr) in (select month, id_nr from table_A where status = 'Y');
```

I suppose that id_nr is not a unique ID in table_b, for otherwise you wouln't have to look at it combined with the month. An appropriate index would hence be:

```
create index idx_b on table_b (id_nr, month);
```

Or maybe, if you work a lot with the month, it may be a good idea to even partition the table by month. This could speed up queries, updates, and deletes immensely.

For table_a I suggest

```
create index idx_a on table_a (status, id_nr, month);
```

which is a covering index. The first column will help find the desired rows quickly; the other two columns will be available without having to read the table row.

Comment: Hi, but I need the month, id_nr combination to be updated or deleted, so did not use "IN".

Comment: `(month, id_nr)` *is* the month, id_nr combination.